# AdView and FloatingActionButton overlap while using CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, admob, floating-action-button, android-snackbar, android-coordinatorlayout

After incorporating the new `CoordinatorLayout` in one of my layouts, I have an issue with `Adview`s overlapping with `FloatingActionButton`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Source:** https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/include_list_viewpager.xml

If I take the same layout and incorporate an `AdView` below the `FloatingActionButton` it causes the `FloatingActionButton` to no longer work with the `SnackBars`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="@string/app_ad" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Simple Admob example to reproduce:**

```
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
    ((AdView)findViewById(R.id.ad_view)).loadAd(adRequest);
```

### I have two issues:

- Overlapping Views (most likely because `CoordinatorLayout` extends `FrameLayout`)
- Adding other views in the same layout as the `FloatingActionButton` cause it to no longer to move or "coordinate" with the `SnackBar`

### Images:

[image: Overlap]

[image: No Animation]

### How can I implement this correctly?

Comment: Looks like valid question, and your query has solved my some other issue. thanks. +1 for your question

Comment: @Naruto Thank you. This affected some my applications and I figured I would try and ask the community. I do not like all the "nested" layouts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After posting, I decided to try and wrap the entire `CoordinatorLayout` layout in a `LinearLayout` and it seems to work well. Maybe someone knows of a better way?

I am not sure this is the best way as there are many nested views:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="@string/app_ad" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe you can use FrameLayout instead of LinearLayout, it should be more lightweight.

Comment: This solution is nice, but I have overlapping with it :(

Answer (score 1):

Probably not what you were looking for, but you can at least align the `FloatingActionButton`, like so

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="@string/app_ad" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/adView"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end|right"
/>
```

As the `CoordinatorLayout` is a `FrameLayout`, you want to have the fab after the `AdView`, as

> Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top

[image: fab centered on ad]